# Plotly No module named 'graph'

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to use graph module for plot and trace_values but I come across with this error:

No module named 'graph'

Any help with be greatly appreciated!

```
import plotly
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

from graph import plot, trace_values

x_values = list(range(-30, 30, 1))
y_values = list(map(lambda x: output_at(three_x_squared_minus_eleven, x),x_values))

three_x_squared_minus_eleven_trace  = trace_values(x_values, y_values, mode = 'lines')
plot([three_x_squared_minus_eleven_trace], {'title': '3x^2 - 11'})
```

Comment: are you sure the name of the module is `graph `?

Comment: Are you sure that the `graph` module is installed on your system? Also, the module named `graph` at [PyPI.org](https://pypi.org/project/graph/) is not about graphing but about the data structure about a network. That module is in alpha status and has not been updated since 2005. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: It seems that the OP uses plotly so this explains the error. I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet looks like the one from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/learn-co-students/introduction-to-derivatives-lab-data-science-alpha), I found the exact same snippet of code defined in their `README`.

They have defined another python module named `graph` in this repository.

In this context, the

```py
from graph import plot, trace_values
```

is legit.

I suppose you don't have this module locally? If you `git clone` their repo and run the same script the function should properly load.

If you are looking for a Python graph library, you can take a look at [`NetworkX`](https://networkx.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `plotly` and probably following some kind of tutorial like [this](https://learn.co/lessons/plotly-lab). You need to define these functions. You need the following to make it work:

```
import plotly
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

def plot(figure):
    plotly.offline.iplot(figure)

def trace_values(x_values, y_values, mode = 'markers', name="data"):
    pass

sample_trace = {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 3, 4]}
other_sample_trace = {'x': [2, 3, 4], 'y': [5, 3, 4]}
sample_figure = {'data': [sample_trace, other_sample_trace], 'layout': {'title': 'Our sample plot'}}
plot(sample_figure)
```

### EDIT 1:

Apparently there is a Github page for this. You can see the function definition here: https://github.com/learn-co-students/introduction-to-derivatives-lab-data-science-alpha/blob/master/graph.py

In this context, `from graph import plot, trace_values` can be used given that the repository is cloned.

Just download the repository from [here](https://github.com/learn-co-students/introduction-to-derivatives-lab-data-science-alpha) and then `from graph import plot, trace_values` should work if you are inside the folder (`introduction-to-derivatives-lab-data-science-alpha-master`)